# Why NumPy arrays over standard library arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

If I only need 1D arrays, what are the performance and size-in-memory benefits of using NumPy arrays over Python standard library arrays?  Or are there any?

Let's say I have arrays of at least thousands of elements, and I want: fast direct access-by-index times and I want the smallest memory footprint possible.  Is there a performance benefit to using this:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

over this:

```
from array import array
a = array('i', [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Standard Python `list`s would have fast access-by-index times, but any `array` implementation will have a much smaller memory footprint. What is a decent compromise solution?

Comment: With a 5 elements array, probably not.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Sorry, I thought it was clear that I was just showing an example. I am intersted in longer arrays. Question edited.

Comment: If you need to loop over your data structures you might want to look into cython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy` is great for its fancy indexing, broadcasting, masking, flexible view on data in memory, many of its numerical methods and more. If you just want a container to hold data, then use an `array.array` or why not even a simple `list`?

I suggest taking a look at the [numpy tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial).

Comment: Well, looping over a Python `list` is not particularly fast. And my current application is scientific computing, where I will be doing a lot of looping and direct access-by-index. I have updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Looping over `array.array` and `numpy.ndarray` instances is also slow.  The whole point of using numpy arrays is that you can perform numeric operations on the whole array at once, which is both syntactically cleaner and offers major performance benefits because the loop is pushed down to C level.

Comment: Give [this tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) a read. Basically instead of looping over an array to perform an operation, `numpy` allows you to do this: `a *= 2` to multiply each element by two in place. `a * a` multiply two vectors element-wise.

Comment: @DSM That is good to know.  As that is not really my use-case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

this depends entirely on what you're planning on *doing* with the array.

```
>>> from array import array
>>> a = array('i', [1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a + a
array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Note that the standard lib treats an array much more like a sequence which might not be desireable (or maybe it is ... Only you can decide that)

Comment: I am mostly interested in performance speed of looping over reasonably large arrays. (For scientific computing purposes.)

Comment: @theJollySin Numpy is mostly about calling C modules so that no loops are completed in python. As a generic statement: if you are looping over large arrays in python and care even the slightest about run time you are doing it wrong. If you need element wise control you should look into a lower level language.